# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Using this dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a reproducible, static dataframe.
# 1 minute SPY data. Skip to the bottom...
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:30",
        "open": "457.2",
        "high": "457.29",
        "low": "456.78",
        "close": "456.9383",
        "volume": "594142"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:31",
        "open": "456.94",
        "high": "457.07",
        "low": "456.8",
        "close": "456.995",
        "volume": "194061"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:32",
        "open": "456.99",
        "high": "457.22",
        "low": "456.84",
        "close": "457.21",
        "volume": "186114"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:33",
        "open": "457.22",
        "high": "457.45",
        "low": "457.2011",
        "close": "457.308",
        "volume": "294158"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:34",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.4",
        "low": "457.25",
        "close": "457.32",
        "volume": "172574"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:35",
        "open": "457.31",
        "high": "457.48",
        "low": "457.18",
        "close": "457.44",
        "volume": "396668"
    },
    {
        "time": "2021-10-26 9:36",
        "open": "457.48",
        "high": "457.6511",
        "low": "457.44",
        "close": "457.57",
        "volume": "186777"
    }
 ])
```

... I want to calculate a boolean column that says `True` if the TIME (date not important) in the "time" column is within the start and end time, else `False`. What I have so far is:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.strptime("09" + "31", "%H%M").time()
end_time = datetime.strptime("09" + "33", "%H%M").time()

# Convert datetime column to datetime objects
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

df['isWithinTimeframe'] = np.where(df['time'].time() >= start_time and df['time'].time() < end_time, True, False)
```

I currently get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'time'
```

I read in a few other solutions that you need to invoke `.dt` between `df['time']` and `.time()`, so I tried that also, but get:

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Ideas?

Comment: use - `df['time'].dt.time` ; `.dt.time()` would give you the second error, and `df['time'].time()` would give you the first

Comment: Tried this, but get the error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` as it's a series I'm dealing with. Thanks tho!

Comment: ACTUALLY you were right, I had to change the using `&` not `and` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of necessary corrections will get you the boolean flag.

As mentioned in the comments, you have to use `.dt` to access the datetime methods & properties (similar to how `.str` provides access to the string methods & properties

instead of `and` use the bitwise-and operator `&`, and to avoid an error due to operator precedence, the `>=` & `<` comparisons have to be put in parentheses.

```py
df['isWithinTimeframe'] = (df.time.dt.time >= start_time) & (df.time.dt.time < end_time)
```

df now looks like:

|  | time | open | high | low | close | volume | isWithinTimeframe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-10-26 09:30:00 | 457.2 | 457.29 | 456.78 | 456.938 | 594142 | False |
| 1 | 2021-10-26 09:31:00 | 456.94 | 457.07 | 456.8 | 456.995 | 194061 | True |
| 2 | 2021-10-26 09:32:00 | 456.99 | 457.22 | 456.84 | 457.21 | 186114 | True |
| 3 | 2021-10-26 09:33:00 | 457.22 | 457.45 | 457.201 | 457.308 | 294158 | False |
| 4 | 2021-10-26 09:34:00 | 457.31 | 457.4 | 457.25 | 457.32 | 172574 | False |
| 5 | 2021-10-26 09:35:00 | 457.31 | 457.48 | 457.18 | 457.44 | 396668 | False |
| 6 | 2021-10-26 09:36:00 | 457.48 | 457.651 | 457.44 | 457.57 | 186777 | False |

Answer (score 1):

Coerce column time into datetime and set it as index. That allows you to use the between_time clause to select what suites your condition. Because that returns a subdf, check if the time column in the subdf is in the main df. Code below

```
df['isWithinTimeframe']=df['time'].isin(df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['time'])).between_time(start_time,end_time)['time'])


     time    open      high       low     close  volume  \
0  2021-10-26 9:30   457.2    457.29    456.78  456.9383  594142   
1  2021-10-26 9:31  456.94    457.07     456.8   456.995  194061   
2  2021-10-26 9:32  456.99    457.22    456.84    457.21  186114   
3  2021-10-26 9:33  457.22    457.45  457.2011   457.308  294158   
4  2021-10-26 9:34  457.31     457.4    457.25    457.32  172574   
5  2021-10-26 9:35  457.31    457.48    457.18    457.44  396668   
6  2021-10-26 9:36  457.48  457.6511    457.44    457.57  186777   

   isWithinTimeframe  
0              False  
1               True  
2               True  
3               True  
4              False  
5              False  
6              False  
print(df.where(df['life_day
```